# Mongo VersionError race condition - find, modify and .save()

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I simplify my Mongoose models in the following way: let's say I have a model `Bank`, with subdocuments `Users`, each of them has an array of `Transfers`

```js
    BankSchema = {
     bank_name : {type:String},
     users : [
              {
                user_name : {type:String},
                transfers : [
                              {
                                amount : {type:Number},
                                date   : {type:Date}
                              }
                            ]
               }
             ]
    }
```

The BankSchema has a method to add transfers, that finds the correct User and add to him the transfer

```js
BankSchema.methods.addTransfer(user_name, new_transfer)
{
 var bank = this;
 for(let u in bank.users)
  {
   if(bank.users[u].name == user_name)
    { 
     bank.users[u].transfers.push(new_transfer); 
     break;
    }
  }
 return bank.save(); // promise
}
```

Now, let's say I have a csv of transfers of different banks to import, so I do

```js
/*
 csv will give rows like {bank_id:'', user_name:'', transition:{} }
*/

for(let i in csv)
{
 var row = csv[i];
 Bank.findById(row.bank_id)
   .then(function(bank)
       {
        // addTransfer also save() the document
        bank.addTransfer(row.user_name, row.transition);
       })
   .catch(function(err)
      {
       console.error(err); 
       // this gives:  VersionError: No matching document found for...
      })
}
```

In the loop, each time I find the Bank, modify it and save. So I am not modifying several times in parallel the same version, but each time a find again it. I thought this was enough to avoid the Mongo VersionError, but probably I was wrong.

Is it not possible to have concurrent "adds of subdocuments?"

```
"mongoose": "^5.4.20",
$npm --version 6.4.1
```

======= UPDATE 1 =======

After the discussion with Oleg (see his answer), I am thinking just handle that error, and try again. Besides the massive import, at runtime it may happen that different users add transfers at the same time. But they should be pretty rare situations, so a "try again" may be a solution? Something like:

```js
function main() 
{
 for(let i in csv)
  {
    var row = csv[I];

    // in parallel, not blocking
    addTransferToBank(row.bank_id, row.user_name, row.transition); 
   }
}

function addTransferToBank(bank_id, user_name, transition)
{
 var deferred = Q.defer();
 Bank.findById(bank_id)
   .then(function(bank)
       {
        // addTransfer also save() the document
        return bank.addTransfer(user_name, transition);
       })
   .then(function()
       {
         deferred.resolve(true); // ok, done
       })
   .catch(function(err)
      {
            if(err && err.name && err.name == "VersionError")
                {
                 // TRY AGAIN
                 deferred.resolve(addTransferToBank(bank_id, user_name, transition)); // I could also run it after a timeout
                }
            else
                { deferred.reject(err);  }
      })
return deferred.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the promise you are returning from addTransfer to resolve before moving on to the next transfer.

If this doesn't work:

```
    return bank.addTransfer(row.user_name, row.transition);
```

... you may need to wait for it explicitly using some other mechanism.

Comment: I can do this, in this specific case since I am importing the data. But what if, in production, different users adds transfers at the same time?

Comment: You need to use different exclusion strategies then. One is find-and-modify in a single operation, and your application needs to handle concurrent updates and retry. Another possibility is multi-document transactions added in MongoDB 4.0.

Comment: If I use  find-and-modify, does the `pre-save hook` still work?

Comment: I may use a static var in the server, that stores which subdocument I am modifying, handling the locks in the Pre and Post Save-Hook. But, what should I lock? the whole document `Bank`, the subdocument `User` or the sub-subdocument `Transfers`?

Comment: Find and modify means https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/. The operation tells the database to update a document based on a condition (such as the current version that you are expecting the document to have).  If the version doesn't match due to concurrent update, the update won't be made and the application needs to fetch the new document, calculate the update again and retry.

Comment: "static var" won't work when you have more than one server.

Comment: right, I should use a DB also for locks.  Using `findAndModify()`, is it possible to do what I need? Add an element to a sub-subdocument array. And does `pre-save hook` work? thank you

Comment: It is possible but you need to redesign your solution.

Comment: I am thinking that the less invasive solution, may be catching the error, and retry again. I have added an *update* to my question. Could it be reasonable, or it's too dirty?

Comment: Financial operations is not a place to "hope for the best". Please use a pattern that is understood to be provably correct.